# Set a global require

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have the following code snippet

```
function initializeWorld()
    _G.require = function(name)
            if package.loaded[name] == nil then
                    local result, err = external.MyAPIEndpoint:LUAInclude(name .. '.lua') 
                    if err == nil then
                        if result ~= nil then
                                package.loaded[name] = result
                        else
                                package.loaded[name] = true
                        end

                        return package.loaded[name]
                    else
                        local errTxt = err .. "\r\n" .. debug.traceback()
                        error(errTxt, 1)
                    end
            else
                    return package.loaded[name]
            end
    end

    helloWorld = require ("helloWorld")
    print(helloWorld.welcome())
end

function initializeUniverse()
    _G.require = function(name)
            if package.loaded[name] == nil then
                    local result, err = external.MyAPIEndpoint:LUAInclude(name .. '.lua') 
                    if err == nil then
                        if result ~= nil then
                                package.loaded[name] = result
                        else
                                package.loaded[name] = true
                        end

                        return package.loaded[name]
                    else
                        local errTxt = err .. "\r\n" .. debug.traceback()
                        error(errTxt, 1)
                    end
            else
                    return package.loaded[name]
            end
    end

    helloUniverse = require ("helloUniverse")

    print(helloUniverse.welcome())

end
```

As you can see that the `global requires` is used in two different places. once in `initializeWorld` and the other in `initializeUniverse`

Can I make ammendments to the code such that it is loaded only once ?

Thanks

Comment: Remove it from whichever function is called last? If it's a race condition, define it externally (possibly conditionally load it in both).

Comment: `local local_require = function(name)...end; function initializeWorld() _G.require = local_require; ... end; function initializeUniverse() _G.require = local_require; ... end;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't overwrite the global `require` function. If you want to run third-party- or user-code you can just sandbox it, and otherwise you can simply use a different name like `my_require()` or `load_awesome_stuff()`

I will assume that you don't know which of the two functions `initializeWorld()` and `initializeUniverse()` is called first, though this solution works either way.

Simply define the function under some name, whichever you like most, but if possible avoiding the global `require`, at some point where you can be sure that it runs before either of those two initialize functions. Then you can just use it in both of them. If you want it to be called `require`, you could just define it locally in the fucntion body like `local require = my_require; require "some_stuff"`

Comment: thanks.. i now know what I need to do - thanks once again.